# Paypal Express Checkout shipping calculation with cURL

Tags: php, curl, paypal, express-checkout

I'm attempting to implement a shopping cart on my website that is hosted through third-party hosting so I don't have the APIs or other requirements installed to be able to use PHP, so I am using PHP to execute cURL calls instead.

I need to calculate shipping costs for my items, but I'm not sure how to make that happen with the setup I have. I know PayPal has a shipping calculator, is it not possible to use that? If not, how can I set up shipping costs without having access to the APIs?

I have been pointed toward the [Instant Update API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/), but I don't have a way to install the APIs to use it. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the shipping calculator inside PayPal Profile applies only to Website Payment Standards(buy now,add to cart etc) . For making API calls with Express checkout, you need to send few parameters in your CURL API request.

You need to pass `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SHIPPINGAMT` in your CURL request.Available [variables](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/).

P.S You don't need any special permission to make API calls.Just `PHP+CURL`will do.

Ex CURL to the below URL:
https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?&user=xxxxxxxxxx&pwd=xxxxxxxxxx&signature=xxxxxxxxxx&version=70.0&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&RETURNURL=http://www.paypal.com/test.php&CANCELURL=http://www.paypal.com/test.php&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&AMT=50&CURRENCYCODE=USD&PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SHIPPINGAMT=5.00

Comment: This is my first time using cURL in any form, so I'm not really sure how I'd pass that in my cURL request.

Also, don't I need to have the SDKs to use the APIs? How do I get access to the necessary classes in order to do use the APIs with PHP+CURL?

Comment: But doesn't that specify a shipping amount? I need to calculate international shipping using the shipping address. And that looks like NVP not CURL, isn't it?